# Subtract time and show difference in mins:secs format

Tags: javascript

I want to accurately display the difference between two times. The different should be displayed in a format such as mm:ss

```
    methods: {
        calcuateTimeDifference: function (startTime, endTime) {
            let result = 0;
            if (startTime && endTime) {
                let start = startTime.split(":");
                let end = endTime.split(':');
                let startTimeInHrs = (parseFloat(start[0]/3600) + parseFloat(start[1]/60) + parseFloat(start[2]/3600));
                let endTimeInHrs = (parseFloat(end[0]/3600) + parseFloat(end[1]/60) + parseFloat(end[2] /3600));
                result = endTimeInHrs - startTimeInHrs;
            }
            return result.toFixed(2);

        },
```

**Using this function - the difference between the following times: 16:03:01 - 16:04:01 - I get the result as -32.00.**

Comment: Why are you dividing the number of hours by 3600? You want to multiply by 3600 to get the amount of seconds. Same for minutes, multiply instead of divide. And then you also divide seconds by 3600 for some reason. Just leave that alone.

Comment: Fixed that but still not getting the time in the following format  mm:ss

Comment: Well you've got no code that attempts to do that...

Answer (score 0):

1. `split` the strings on `:` to get the hours, minutes, and seconds
2. convert all to seconds and add them to get the total seconds from each time
3. subtract the two to get the difference in seconds
4. convert the difference seconds to hours, minutes and seconds using the modules operator(`%`)
5. format the result for appropriate display

```js
let start = "16:03:01";
let end  = "16:04:05";

let time = calcuateTimeDifference(start, end);
console.log(time);

function calcuateTimeDifference(startTime, endTime) {

    let result = 0;
    if (startTime && endTime) {

        const start = startTime.split(':').map(Number);
        const end = endTime.split(':').map(Number);

        const startSeconds = (60*60) * start[0] + 60*start[1] + start[2];
        const endSeconds = (60*60) * end[0] + 60*end[1] + end[2];
        
        const diffSeconds = endSeconds - startSeconds;
        
        seconds = parseInt((diffSeconds) % 60);
        minutes = parseInt((diffSeconds/60) % 60);
        hours = parseInt((diffSeconds/(60*60)) % 24);

        //append `0` infront if a single digit
        hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;

    } 

     console.log("Invalid Input");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calcuateTimeDifference(startTime, endTime) {
    let toSeconds = (time) => {
        let [h, m, s] = time.split(':');
        return h * 360 + m * 60 + +s;
    };

    let d = Math.abs(toSeconds(startTime) - toSeconds(endTime));

    let mm = String(Math.floor(d / 60));
    if (mm.length == 1) mm = '0' + mm;

    let ss = String(d % 60);
    if (ss.length == 1) ss = '0' + ss;

    return `${mm}:${ss}`;
}
```